# BlueStacks Installation failed older sdk error

Tags: android, android-xml, bluestacks

Hi everyone I'm trying to install an apk that I've designed with minsdk version of 14 and target of 19 onto bluestacks and its failing. What's weird is that I installed an app with the same api version of 14/19 on this very same bluestacks player a month ago(I deleted it now though to swap it with the new apk). Please let me know what api I should be developing in for bluestacks. Here's my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.demoww"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/earth"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoadScreen"
        android:label="@string/Linking_players" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUp"
        android:label="@string/Signup" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".suggestedfriends" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".search" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".requests" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".raul_profile" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".raul_message" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".profile" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".messages" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".friendslist" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>

</application>
<!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!--
 To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
 option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies







-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Why do you use BlueStacks for testing apps instead of a real emulator like Genymotion?

Comment: I find that bluestacks is much faster than genymotion

Comment: Ok. So what exactly do you mean saying it's failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your BlueStacks is installed on a Windows PC, you can check its version by hovering over its taskbar icon.

[image]

Comment: this answer does not answer the question

Answer (score 8):

You can check which version of Android your version of BlueStacks is designed for by looking at the table below:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/BlueStacks_App_Player

The Android version of my BlueStacks is 4.0.4. The API level is 15.

According to the table, the latest version (beta) conforms to 4.4.2 (KitKat).

Unless, you have that version, you have to lower the API level for your apk to 15 or even lower.

If your BlueStacks is installed on a PC, you can check its version by:

Start-> type "regedit"

In registry editor, go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" , "SOFTWARE", "BlueStacks" and it should be there under "Version".

[These instructions to find the version number of an installed BlueStacks were originally posted by intheGame.]